# Print 10 digits per row/line using Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printing

How do I print 10 numbers per line/row? I want an output like this:

```
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
1 8 27 64 125 216 343 512 729 1000
................
...................
```

But what I am getting now is muddled up.

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 3 9 27 81 243 4 16 64 256 1024 5 25 125 625 3125 6 36 216 1296 7776 7 49 343 2401 16807 8 64 512 4096 32768 9 81 729 6561 59049 10 100 1000 10000 100000
```

This is the snippet

```
public class NumberOnly
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        for(int count = 1; count <= 10; count++) {

                 System.out.print(count + " ");
                 System.out.print((int) Math.round(Math.pow(count, 2))  + " ");
                 System.out.print((int) Math.round(Math.pow(count, 3))  + " ");
                 System.out.print((int) Math.round(Math.pow(count, 4))  + " ");
                 System.out.print((int) Math.round(Math.pow(count, 5))  + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes, can you post that?

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, religious or spiritual invocations, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this code. This works the way you want.

```
public class NumberOnly
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<=10; j++)
            {
                System.out.print((int)Math.round(Math.pow(j, i)) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is :

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
>
> 1 8 27 64 125 216 343 512 729 1000
>
> 1 16 81 256 625 1296 2401 4096 6561 10000
>
> 1 32 243 1024 3125 7776 16807 32768 59049 100000

Here, we use 2 loops, the outer loop that runs 5 times because we need the numbers 1-10 to be raised to powers 1-5.
The inner loop runs 10 times because the numbers are 1-10.
We use **System.out.print()** in the inner loop because we don't want newline when all the numbers are being raised to the same power.
When the inner loop ends, we use **System.out.println()** which puts all the numbers raised to the next power in the new line.

Example -

1-10 raised to power 1, are put in the first line.

1-10 raised to power 2, are put in the next(i.e. second) line.
and so on...